# How to conditionally replace Pandas dataframe column values from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1, 2, 3],
                    "col2":["a", "b", "c"]})

df1
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2
0   1       a
1   2       b
2   3       c
```

And the second one:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    "col2":["x", "y", "z", "q", "w"]})
df2
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2
0   1       x
1   2       y
2   3       z
3   4       q
4   5       w
```

Additional info:
`col1` in both data frames have unique values.
`col2` does not necessarily have unique values.

What to achieve:
How can I replace values of `col2` in `df1` with the corresponding `col2` values from `df2` from the matching `col1` values?

Desired final content of `df1` is supposed to be as following:

```
    col1    col2
0   1       x
1   2       y
2   3       z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dict by zipping the df2 columns.
Use map to transfer values over to df1. Code below

```
df1['col2']=df1['col1'].map(dict(zip(df2['col1'],df2['col2'])))
```

Answer (score 1):

try `.map`

```py
df1['col2'] = df1['col1'].map(df2.set_index('col1')['col2'])

#   col1    col2
# 0 1   x
# 1 2   y
# 2 3   z
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Your suggested solution works as well!